# vim put a line from current cursor position to next line

Tags: vim

You can pull a line up in vim using Shift + j at the current line. How do you do the reverse i.e put all the words following cursor below the current line ?

Comment: `yy and p` will yank the current line and paste it below.

Comment: I typically insert a carriage return with "i<enter><esc>".

Comment: I guess you pull a line up by "^i<backspace>" :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I go to the whitespace where I want to cut the line and hit `r<CR>`.

Comment: 'r' stands for replace current character, so what you do is replacing current character with newline.. <3 vim!

Answer (score 2):

Doing this is a pretty simple, most people just enter insert mode, stick a newline in there and return to normal mode like this `i<entr><esc>` There isn't a faster way to do this, however if you really want, you can map this to a key in your vimrc.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for . I didnt want to put "bc" at the end of second line, instead I wanted "bc" to become the second line.